# why spring boot not use application.properties in test resources first?

Tags: spring-boot

I have a special properties file in test resources directory

```
└── test
    ├── java
    │   └── com
    │       └── inter3i
    │               ├── dao
    │               │   └── FooMapperTest.java
    └── resources
        └── application.properties
```

in this application.properties file I specify the MySQL URL.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://139.224.xxx.xxx/foo?useSSL=false
```

then I execute a test

```
mvn test -Dtest=com.foo.reportapi.dao.FooMapperTest
```

but it is failed  because

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JDBC Connection for transaction; nested exception is com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:289) ~[spring-jdbc-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar:4.3.10.RELEASE]
```

but actually the MySQL URK is OK, why does it have this error? From wireshark I know it actually connected to another URL

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://192.168.0.25/foo
```

which configured in `application-default.properties`

```
src
├── main
│   └── resources
│       ├── application-default.properties
```

So why is it so counterintuitive? I think test classes should use `application.properties` in test resources first.

In addition I have to use wireshark to find which URL it is connecting to, how could I get Spring Boot to output MySQL URL info explicitly?

Comment: Per https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html `application-{profile}` is higher priority than `application`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As jonrsharpe already mentioned, a specific profile has precedence over the application.properties file - here you find the documentation of the PropertySource order:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

You can fix it in serveral ways:

1. rename main/resources/application-default.properties to main/resources/application.properties
2. rename test/resources/application.properties to test/resources/application-default.properties
3. rename test/resources/application.properties to test/resources/application-default-integrationtest.properties and enable the profile with the following annotation on your test class: @ActiveProfiles({"integrationtest"})

I would recommend #3 because it does not depend on classpath priority of main and test elements and states clearly what file is used.

Now to the logging-part of your question.

If you increase the spring log level to "debug" you can see which config files are loaded. You can log a specific property in your own code:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class LogSpringDatasourceUrlProperty {
  @Autowired
  public LogSpringDatasourceUrlProperty(@Value("${spring.datasource.url}") String jdbcUrl){
     log.info( "application uses '{}' as jdbcUrl", jdbcUrl );    
  }
}
```